# Display an alert or a modal when going back from an incomplete from

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, angular2-forms

I have created a form which includes a **username** field and a **save** button.
If we type something in the username field and click back button without saving it, my form should display an alertbox or a modal window asking Do you really want to leave the page?

I found this [article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/06/warning-a-user-before-they-leave-a-form/) but needs something more generic.

**form.html**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title> Data </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<form (ngSubmit)="dataForm(data)" #data="ngForm">
<ion-item>
<ion-input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button large type="submit">Save</button>
<form>
</ion-content>
```

I am using ionic2 typescript and angular2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ionViewCanLeave()` [lifecycle hook](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) to show your alert when the user tries to leave the page, do like this:

```
public canLeave: boolean = false; // Create a property in your component

ionViewCanLeave(){
  if(!thiscanLeave){ // IF canLeave IS FALSE ENTER THE IF STATEMENT TO CONFIRM IF THE USER WANTS TO LEAVE THE PAGE. IF IT'S TRUE RETURN TRUE SAYING IT CAN LEAVE.
    if(confirm("Do you really want to leave?")){
      this.canLeave = true; // YOU'LL NEED TO SET YOUR PROPERTY TO TRUE WHENEVER YOU NEED TO LEAVE THE PAGE, BEEING A POP, PUSH OR SETROOT.
      this.navCtrl.pop();
    };
  };
  return true;
}
```

This way it'll always check if the user can leave the page.

Since you're not using Angular's FormBuilder to check if the user has inputed something in your form (you just want to warn if the user has an incomplete form, if it hasn't typed anything there's no need to alert him) you can create a simple function that'll set your `canLeave` to false, something like:

Your .TS

```
public canLeave: boolean = true;
```

Your HTML

```
<ion-item>
<ion-input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" required(input)="canLeave = false"></ion-input>
```

Hope this helps.